# Filter clause for aggregate functions

Tags: mysql, sql

It seems there is an error in my sql syntax. Here is the command I'm running.:

```
select day(deliverydate),
       sum(total_amount) FILTER (WHERE payment_option='EBS'),
       sum(total_amount) FILTER (WHERE payment_option='COD')
from orders
where month(deliverydate)=2 and
      year(deliverydate)=2019
group by day(deliverydate)
order by 1;
```

Is there a better way for the output to be:
[the nos will be from data obviously](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yPu0x.jpg)

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: It is helpful to provide a sample of your input along with the desirable output. You will, also, need to provide the version of SQL (MySQL, Oracle) since sql is too broad.

Comment: Even though `filter` is part of the SQL standard, only a few DBMS products support it (mainly Postgres and SQLite)

Comment: I'm working with mysql 5.5 currently. @JoPapou13

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would recommend writing this as:

```
select day(deliverydate),
       sum(case when payment_option = 'EBS' then total_amount end),
       sum(case when payment_option = 'COD' then total_amount end)
from orders
where deliverydate >= '2019-02-01' and
      deliverydate < '2019-03-01'
group by day(deliverydate)
order by 1;
```

Note the change to the date logic.  This makes the `where` clause more index-friendly.

Also, if `deliverydate` has no time component, there is no need for `day(deliverydate)`.  You can just use `deliverydate` in the `select` and `group by` clauses.  This makes it easier to extend the query to multiple months.  If there is a time component, use `date()` instead of `day()`.

If you have lots of other payment options, then adding `and payment_option in ('EBS', 'COD')` to the `where` clause might also help performance.

Comment: Thanks for your valuable time Sir. Appreciate it.